# linux if else fails for some IP's

Tags: linux, scripting, awk

i am using the following code with if then to mount. It works for some IP's, it does not work for some IP's especially for FAILURE statement.

Here is the code

```
is_mounted() {
    mount | grep -qohw "$1"
}


{
pass=
for ip in  123.456.789  223.456.789
do
    if is_mounted "$ip"
    then
        echo -e " STACK MOUNT \e[1;33mALREADY\e[00m AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m "
        pass=1
        break
    fi
    mount -t nfs -o ro,nolock "$ip:/opt/media/" /mount/stack &>/dev/null
    if is_mounted "$ip"
    then
        echo -e " STACK MOUNT AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m "
        pass=1
        break
    fi
done
[ "$pass" ] || echo -e " STACK MOUNT NOT AVAILABLE          \e[00;31mFAILED\e[00m"
} | tee /tmp/log
```

These are the IP's which were failing 139.41.170.10, 197.21.82.10, 139.41.170.11, 197.21.82.11, 139.31.125.11. Ideally should work for any IP. Also I want to use all these IP's '**for ip in  139.41.170.10 197.21.82.10 139.41.170.11 197.21.82.11 139.31.125.11**'.
Any AWK suggestion.

Comment: Shouldn't the line before your `for` be `pass=0`? What shell is this? And where is `awk`?

Comment: Is `$1` correctly closed inside the `is_mounted` function?

Answer (score 2):

In your `is_mounted` function you should test the output of `mount` to confirm that something was returned and then return a 0 or 1 accordingly.

Also I would highly encourage you to use the debugging facilities built into `bash`. You'll quickly see what's going wrong rather than have us try and debug it.

Just put a `set -x` at the beginning of the block of code you want to debug and when you want to disable it, `set +x`.

#### Example

```
... some code ...

set -x
... code to debug ...
set +x

... more code ...
```